# Meaning of the free space indication in Deluge

Tags: disk-usage, deluge

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.0.4 using Wubi with my current Windows Vista. I have already installed all the 265 updates from the Ubuntu software center and downloaded Deluge from there. My hardrive is 80GB according to the disc usage analyzer. It also says 31.2 GB used and 47.8GB free. The confusion comes when I run Deluge. At the bottom it says 2.0GB free space. Is that 2.0GB just a size set from the torrent client and can be changed or am I limited to just that 2.0GB?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please give meaningful titles to your questions. You can find advice [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Comment: Most probably, Deluge refers to the size allocated to the Ubuntu file system. Have a look at the [wubi faq](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php) for more info.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer could you mark it as your [best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) and it will close the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Free Space statusbar values are calculated from the partition containing the `Download to` directory, specified in Preferences.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems when I installed ubuntu 12.0.4 I only allocated 6gb worth of storage space. An uninstall and re install with more storge fixed the problem.